# Is a class B endorsement required for a Private checkride?

Tags: faa-regulations, checkride

I was just wondering if a Class B endorsement was required for a Private Pilot Check-ride in the US?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! For questions about regulations, please always tell us which country you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, this is in the US.

Comment: Do not worry. I have edited the question for you. Please accept or approve the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a Class B endorsement for your PPL Check ride.

By the time you get to you check ride you should have [the first 8 endorsements from this list, provided by the FAA.](http://www.soargbsc.com/inststud/instructor/endorse.pdf)

I will add one caveat to this. During your check ride your examiner will ask you plan a cross country flight. If the route calls for it and you have the endorsement you can plan it through Class B. However if you plan it through Class B your examiner may ask for the endorsement or try and trip you up over it. if you plan a course through Class B *without* the endorsement the DPE may not stop you when you get in the air. Be careful as you can bust a checkride for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, Dave. Really helps a lot!

Comment: Well put, Dave!

Comment: There is a later version of 61-65E, dated 1/6/13, vs  the 11/29/05 document  linked to above. Here is the later one: https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65e_chg_1.pdf

Comment: FAA also has an update Airman Testing Questions & Answers guide, 19 pages of things you might be asking about, so I won't copy it here.  https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/media/questions_answers.pdf